# A filter for for a realtime system?

Tags: filters, filter-design, real-time

Apologies if this is too basic.

I need to implement a band-pass filter, for a realtime system.
Not sure what to use. FIR? IIR? Something else ?

Any tips would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by real-time? Please provide the maximum allowable delay, sampling frequency, and filter requirements. All these are interdependent.

Comment: Sampling frequency 512Hz.  Filter 1Hz-30Hz and as minimum delay as possible. It's EEG data BTW. Thanks @Juancho!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an EEG signal, I suppose you need to keep the shape of the signal. Therefore the filter should have linear phase, so the reasonable way to go is a FIR filter.

If shape (transients) don't matter much for your application, then an IIR filter would be preferable since it will give less end-to-end delay in general.

Note that suprressing 0 - 1 Hz, inevitably gives a group delay of at least 1 second, depending on how sharp the transition should be, so your real-time requirements may conflict with the start frequency.

You may try some filter design tools (e.g. from matlab) to find a reasonable compromise between frequency response and group delay.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit about the "group delay problem" you have mentioned, not 100% sure why it's happened (I Probably missing something very basic ) Thanks this is all very helpful!

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit about the "group delay problem" you have mentioned, not 100% sure why it's happened (I Probably missing something very basic ) Thanks this is all very helpful!